Why is there a difference between the ma-def2-tzvp basis set used in ORCA and downloaded from official website?
I am trying of calculate the electron affinity and ionization energy of Lanthanum using Gaussian 16 A03. Considering that anion is involved, diffuse functions are used, using the b3lyp/ma-def2-tzvp level. Feeling quite strange about the results, a b3lyp/def2-tzvp level is used, and all the calculations are done with ORCA 6.0.0 for comparison. ma-def2-tzvp basis set file for gaussian is downloaded from https://comp.chem.umn.edu/basissets/basis.cgi
. Frequencies' comtribution to enthalpy is considered, using the Shermo program. Results are summarized in the chart below.




ma-def2-tzvp g16
def2-tzvp g16
ma-def2-tzvp orca
def2-tzvp orca




La+
-1433.8043995
-31.2807335
-31.2460066
-31.2459910


La
-1434.4074245
-31.4892755
-31.4518478
-31.4518217


La-
-1434.8120565
-31.5016775
-31.4668714
-31.4643295



One could easily see that the other three computations all give the similar results , close to experimental ones, while the b3lyp/ma-def2-tzvp using Gaussian is giving strange results, not only in the thermodynamic results itself, but also the elctron affinity and ionization energies are abnormally large, so I was wondering where the problem is. I compared the basis set used in the two different programs, and found significant differences between the contraction of ma-def2-tzvp used by Gaussian and ORCA, see below(the left is from Truhlar's website, and the right is from ORCA).The difference is the reason I believe to be the reason for the strange results, so the question I ask is why is there a difference between them.

Update2: 
I was directly citing the .gbs file for Gaussian to read basis set information, but I forgot to make Gaussian read the ECP info, with this added the data returned to normal. REALLY REALLY sorry for wasting all of your precious time just because of my blunder.

It seems that the chart is not correctly rendered

@wzkchem5 When I click into the edit button, the chart is correctly displayed. I don't know what's wrong.  https://imgur.com/a/4gYG3zF

@wzkchem5 Fixed using snapshot instead of markdown

+1 but why is one column labeled "tavp" while the rest are labeled "tzvp"? Also, why not show precisely what the differences in the basis sets are, and precisely where you got them, and the original reference (publication) that describes the basis set as it was first introduced in the literature?

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime the "tavp" is a stupid typo, I'll fix it later, differences will be posted later, thanks for pointing out.

@RTChou - the basis set used in both programs is identical, at least from the numbers you have posted. The contraction coefficients are normalized by all quantum chemistry software packages (at least all that I know of) by default. If you normalize the coefficients, you will see that they are the same up to the accuracy provided.

@Uwe That means that they are really the same basis sets, I got this. So my question turned into why is the gaussian results so strange, with the other three all match with each other.

@RTChou The numbers in the table are exactly what? And what is your input molecule? I guess it is not a single atom as this would not give a vibrational contribution to the enthalpy... If this is including the DFT energy, did you check which ECPs are used with the basis set? How many electrons are removed and placed into the ECP?

Please avoid changing the question. You're very welcome to post a new question if a new question arises!

The question is still the same: Where does the difference come from. Aren't we expected to try to help answering the question?

@Uwe The numbers in the table are electronic energy+ZPE for La atom. I've checked multiplicity to be correct.

@Uwe And, about the ECP, I suppose I made a really stupid mistake. I directly cited the gbs file for Gaussian to read, but I forgot to make Gaussian read the ECP info......I think you could close this question now. Really sorry for wasting your time:(

@Uwe the original post didn't show either of the basis sets, so I gave the best answer that I could based on the information provided. Then the basis sets were shown, which changes the question (and potential answers) a bit (or a lot), but my issue was with the chaging of the entire question (including the title!) from "why are these basis sets different?" to "why am I getting such different energies despite the basis sets being the same". I did try to help the user solve their problem, by encouraging the user to ask the new question. We are not "expected" to help, but we do try :) .

I will begin with this quote from advice that I gave about 3 years ago:

"I try to never use the default basis sets given in any program. I always use my own GENBAS file:  github.com/HPQC-LABS/AI_ENERGIES/blob/master/GENBAS so that I'm 100% sure I know what basis set I'm using. Keep in mind that there's several aug-cc-pCVTZ basis sets out there, depending on who optimized the exponents and what version of the basis set the EMSL Basis Set Exchange had available at the time that it was downloaded."

Examples of differences in basis sets across programs
From time to time, there will be discrepancies between the basis sets internally stored within different computer programs, or between what is internally stored by a program and what is found in a basis set database.
This can be because of:

A simple error when entering the basis set into the program, or
An intended difference in the basis set exponents or contraction coefficients.

For example, many of the basis sets on the EMSL Basis Set Exchange were improved over the years, not just because of finding typos or errors, but because exponents got optimized better. Even for a specific periodic table element, and a basis set with a specific name (like cc-pVDZ), different numbers can be obtained if you optimize the parameters using BFGS vs Nelder-Mead, and the basis set still has the same name either way.
For example, many of the basis sets on the EMSL Basis Set Exchange changed over the years as



One of the most frustrating examples for me was when MOLPRO rounded the following numbers in the output of an aug-cc-pCV6Z calculation:
 0.0000058 became  0.000006
-0.0000011 became -0.000001
 etc.

Since the EMSL Basis Set Exchange didn't have that basis set at the time (similarly, they don't have your ma-def2-TZVP basis set for La either), CFOUR and MRCC calculations were done using a basis set generated from the MOLPRO output which had the rounded numbers, while MOLPRO was secretly doing more accurate calculations with the extra digits that were stored internally but not displayed in the output.
The difference in the 0.0000001 digits of the basis sets led to a discrepancy that was very painful to diagnose after so many back-and-forth messages between Mihaly Kallay and I.
I have seen differences between the basis sets in MOLPRO vs the EMSL Basis Set Exchange (this was probably well-known for aCV5Z and aCV6Z circa 2017), and I have even seen differences between the basis set available from MOLPRO's own website versus the basis set that MOLPRO actually uses internally!
Diagnosing discrepancies in energies with the same basis set
Notice that in the past when I obtained two different energies when using the same basis set and all the same electronic structure methods, I included my basis sets in the input files themselves (and included these in my reports), for example here and here.
In your case, I did not find ma-def2-TZVP or ma-TZVP for La in the MolSSI Basis Set Exchange. I did see one labeled "ma-TZVP" from the website (belonging to the LeBron James of computational chemistry) that you provided, and it is here, but I couldn't view it on my tablet since it had a .gbs extension and the "source" that that webpage mentioned was this one and I didn't find it helpful, so the StatSim online viewer helped me obtain the following:
****
-La     0
S   2   1.00
      5.0873990000          -0.44174952534
      4.2709780000           0.85812466843
S   1   1.00
      2.1823656045           1.0000000
S   1   1.00
      0.48966533785          1.0000000
S   1   1.00
      0.23301675348          1.0000000
S   1   1.00
      0.55719523051E-01            1.0000000
S   1   1.00
      0.22854708808E-01            1.0000000
P   4   1.00
      6.0000000000          -0.11397960924E-01
      3.6808191615           0.14675038550
      2.3265462081          -0.35581819167
      0.64342629633          0.45834955229
P   1   1.00
      0.33584281962          1.0000000
P   1   1.00
      0.16519051916          1.0000000
P   1   1.00
      0.354E-01              1.0000000
D   3   1.00
      1.2675288018          -0.17569274035
      0.89395340284          0.25139922933
      0.33095767339          0.44603267053
D   1   1.00
      0.13461377501          1.0000000
D   1   1.00
      0.51441629839E-01            1.0000000
F   1   1.00
      0.2568300              1.0000000
S   1   1.00
  0.761823626933E-02   1.000
P   1   1.00
  0.118000000000E-01   1.000
****

What ORCA is doing
I do not have access to the ORCA basis sets handy, but I can see from here that they are using AutoAux to "minimally augment" the def2-TZVP basis set, according to the following footnote:

"AutoAux should give a basis set that most reliably reduces the RI error. However, it can occasionally give a linearly-dependent basis (resulting in errors such as ('Error in Cholesky Decomposition of V Matrix')). See more on RI and auxiliary basis sets".

This may be very different from the "ma-TZVP" (it was labeled this way on Don Truhlar's website instead of "ma-def2-TZVP") basis set that you downloaded in Gaussian format. Every single number is different in your table, so I'm not convinced that any of your basis sets are the same (I would aim to tighten convergence thresholds in both computer programs to get closer to nano-Hartree agreement, as I did in the "Curse of the nano-hartree" thread to which I provided a link earlier).
Also, I recommend to try the same study on a different periodic table element, and this will show you whether your problem is isolated to La or if it is more general.
The numbers in your first column (you labeled it ma-def2-tzvp g16, but on Truhlar's website it's labeled ma-TZVP) are very different from the numbers in all other columns, so there might be an issue with the data on Truhlar's website (which is not a problem when using AutoAux to generate the diffuse functions), and you may be able to circumvent this issue by finding the original paper in which ma-TZVP was first defined, and seeing if the basis set's parameters were reported in that paper or in its supplementary material (if it's not, you can contact the author of the paper and ask for the original data, or report a "bug" to Truhlar's team for the error on the website).

On the Truhlar's website, below, there is a note saying"The ma-TZVP basis set is the def2-TZVP basis set with the s and p diffuse basis functions on non-hydrogenic atoms. The "ma" stands for "minimally augmented".". On Page 37 of the ORCA 6.0.0 manual, it states"Minimally augmented def-TZVP variant with diffuse s and p functions according to Truhlar", and both of them refers to the original paper Theor. Chem. Acc., 128:295–305, 2010., which in my opinion means that ma-TZVP is completely the same as ma-def2-tzvp

Also, about the RI problem, i conducted a noRI calculation using b3lyp/ma-def2-tzvp, and the difference between them is only 0.000007Hartree, which is almost no difference. And, RI is using a auxiliary basis set different from the original one, which means that it would not change the definition of the original basis set

Yes, about the BSE, this is indeed not on the website, only on Truhlar's website. And, thank you for the advise that "never use the default basis sets ", which is a problem I've never thought about before

Yes, I recommend to download the original basis set from the original paper, and to enter it into your input file, so that you know precisely which version of ma-def2-TZVP you're using (ORCA's version, or Gaussian's version, or Molpro's version, or BSE's version, or the original version from Truhlar's paper, or maybe your own version which has an error from incorrect copy-pasting from Truhlar's paper [at least the same "incorrect" basis set is consistently used, and defined in the input file and output file so we know what went into the calculation]).

In my answer, I didn't suggest that the RI approximation had anything to do with your energy discrepancies, it was just mentioned in the quote from the ORCA website, which mentioned AutoAux when explaining the minimally augmented basis sets. After the new edit to your question and your comment about ma-def2-TZVP vs ma-TZVP, I agree with ORCA's choice to call it ma-def2-TZVP whereas Truhlar (the original author of it) seems to call it ma-TZVP on his website. If the original paper has the diffuse functions in a table or supplementary material, I'd manually make a corresponding set and use that

Thanks for your comments. @Uwe kindly pointed out that the basis sets are actually the same, only in the normalization factor, so I don't know what's going on with Gaussian's results. I just tried using the ORCA version of ma-def2-TZVP for Gaussian calculations and it turned out to be exactly the same results, which furthur proved that  Uwe is right, ORCA and Truhlar versions are the same.
